# Recursive JSON data parsing using GSON

Tags: java, android, json, gson

Sometime we may have JSON data like,

```
[
  {
    "Name": "Fruits",
    "Quantity": "10",
    "isCheckBox": false,
    "List": [
      {
        "Name": "Mango",
        "Quantiy": "10",
        "iScheckBox": true,
        "List": null
      },
      {
        "Name": "Apple",
        "Quantiy": "10",
        "iScheckBox": false,
        "List": [
          {
            "Name": "Simla",
            "Quantiy": "10",
            "iScheckBox": true,
            "List": null
          },
          {
            "Name": "Fuji",
            "Quantiy": "10",
            "iScheckBox": false,
            "List": []
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "Name": "Fruits",
    "Quantity": "10",
    "isCheckBox": false,
    "List": [
      {
        "Name": "Mango",
        "Quantiy": "10",
        "iScheckBox": true,
        "List": null
      },
      {
        "Name": "Apple",
        "Quantiy": "10",
        "iScheckBox": false,
        "List": [
          {
            "Name": "Simla",
            "Quantiy": "10",
            "iScheckBox": true,
            "List": null
          },
          {
            "Name": "Fuji",
            "Quantiy": "10",
            "iScheckBox": false,
            "List": []
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Note : If the isCheckBox value is false then will check the list values to get the inner objects.

Don't know the end of depth level, it may end, or goes on. How to define the POJO class for JSON data like this?

Comment: Than u need to change response type from backend like this

Comment: That would be bad way to implement json ,AFAIK With out knowing exact response I don't think there would be any way to create POJO

Comment: @Redman right he need to response like   Something like this `{
 "Shopping": {
  "Fruits": {
   "Mango": [{
    "Alphanso": {}

   }, {
    "otherType": {}
   }],
   "apple": [{
     "appleType1": {}
    },
    {
     "otherType": {}
    }
   ]

  }
 },
 "Vegetables": {}

}`

Comment: use http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/ to generate POJO class according to the JSON data of your need

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually the solution is very simple,

Here is entity,

```
public class FruitsEntity {
    String Name;
    String Quantity;
    boolean isCheckBox;
    ArrayList<FruitsEntity> List;
}
```

And you can parse using,

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
ArrayList<FruitsEntity> nestEntities = gson.fromJson(jsonData, new TypeToken<ArrayList<FruitsEntity>>() {
}.getType());
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Shopping
{
private Fruits Fruits;

private String Vegetables;

public Fruits getFruits ()
{
    return Fruits;
}

public void setFruits (Fruits Fruits)
{
    this.Fruits = Fruits;
}

public String getVegetables ()
{
    return Vegetables;
}

public void setVegetables (String Vegetables)
{
    this.Vegetables = Vegetables;
}

@Override
public String toString()
{
    return "ClassPojo [Fruits = "+Fruits+", Vegetables = "+Vegetables+"]";
}}
```

This will be enough for the above given sample. Please try